# Exportar SQLite para MySQL

Tags: mysql

Eu usei o SQLite para um projeto, com ele é possível criar um banco com formato '.db' e ver dentro e tudo mais.

Seria possível exporta em MySQL um arquivo com o banco criado da mesma forma que no SQLite? Eu uso o MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Se for exportar do MySql direto para sqLite, então entendi errado a pergunta. Vou deixar a resposta até um retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você tem a opção de exportar:

Server -> Data export

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você poderá criar um arquivo `dump` ou `script`, com a estrutura das tabelas, com os dados ou não, etc:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: meu banco já ta todo povoado, queria exportar ele com tudo já criado, como faria? e isso alteraria algo no meu banco já criado?

Comment: e nao é q eu queria importa pro slite, so queria saber se tem como criar um arquivo igual o do slite, que é '.db'

Comment: Não. o Mysql não funciona com 1 arquivo só, são diferentes tecnologias. Além do sqlite ser limitado a 2Tb de tamanho (o que é um monstro). Você só consegue exportar um "backup", dessa forma que mostrei.

Comment: ahh, entendi, é que meu professor tinha pedido para criar o banco e tal, pensei que ele queria igual slite, mas acho que so quer os comandos todos, muito obrigado

Comment: Não... o Mysql funciona diferente mesmo. Geralmente os arquivos ficam em `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data` (ProgramData é oculta). Os arquivos são de vários formatos (`.frm, .ibd`, etc). Legal também saber o tipo da tecnologia, por exemplo o [InnoDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB).